# Java ImageIcon Animation Flashing

Tags: java, animation, imageicon

Form some reason when it switches Icon's the image flashes. I'm also having this problem even more when I try to create objects then try to make them move by passing the x and y through as parameters on the object. Any help would be great.

```
public class Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener, KeyListener{

static Main main;
Render render;
Timer timer;

static int x,y,count;

ImageIcon player1 = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Kyle\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Testing52\\src\\testing52\\Player1.png");
ImageIcon player2 = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Kyle\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Testing52\\src\\testing52\\Player2.png");

Main(){

    render = new Render();
    timer = new Timer(100,this);

    setVisible(true);
    setSize(500,500);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);
    addKeyListener(this);
    add(render);

    timer.start();

}

public void render(Graphics g){

    count += 1;

    if(count < 20){
         player1.paintIcon(this, g, x, y);
    }

    if(count > 20){
        player2.paintIcon(this, g, x, y);
    }
    if(count > 40){
        count = 0;
    }

}


public static void main(String [] args){

    main = new Main();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    System.out.println(count);
    render.repaint();  
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int id = e.getKeyCode();

    int speed = 4;

    if(id == KeyEvent.VK_UP){

        y -= speed;     
    }

    if(id == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){

        y += speed;
    }

    if(id == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){

        x -= speed;
    }

    if(id == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){

        x += speed;
    }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
}

}
```

Render class.

```
 public class Render extends JPanel {

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Main.main.render((Graphics)g);
}
```

}

Comment: Figured It out. I had to change " if (count > 20)  " to "if (count >= 20)". as well as move "count += 1" to the ActionListener

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that could make your animation smoother is if you called `revalidate()` in your action event after `repaint()`.